# Array Binding with Electronjs/SerialPort & React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, serial-port, electron, spread-syntax

I'm struggling since few days with a reducers, even if after the action the state seems right, React Component does not update...

```
if (getPorts.test(action)) {
  var service = new SerialService();
  var dataResult = new Array<any>();
  service.listDevices(function (err: any, data: Array<any>) {
    data.forEach((item) => {
      dataResult.push({ ...item })
    });
  });
  return {
     ...state,
     ports: dataResult
  };
}
```

I have tried many ways, with or without spread operator (using object.assign())

From my understanding, is might be missing something because of the callback that list devices, guess i'm not managing well how i should update the UI.

Any ideas or advise ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume above code snippets are part of reducer. Reducer *should be* synchronous always, you can't expect asynchronous update in your callback to update connected component in render cycle correctly. Try to look for redux middlewares to support async actions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are right, this is just a part of my reducer. I will have a look at midddlewares.